# How to select randomly from a list of strings a token excluding numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I know that in python in order to randomly pull a word from a token we could do:

In:

```
import random 
s = 'hi there 3'
words = s.split() 
random.choice(words)
```

Out:

```
3
```

However, how can I choose the next word (in this case `hi`) instead of a number? I would like to always guarantee that I am pulling a string not a number?.

Comment: Why should the `3` be replaced with `hi` and not `there`?

Comment: Both are valid @UlrichEckhardt it was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following list comprehension to extract non-numerical words:

```
words = [i for i in s.split() if i.isalpha()]
['hi', 'there']
```

So your code would look like

```
s = 'hi there 3'
words = [i for i in s.split() if i.isalpha()]
random.choice(words)
```

Comment: so first I need to compute the words?

Comment: I am working with the full sentence I just want to pick up anything that is not a number

Comment: Yes, the current solution should do

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words = [ x for x in s.split() if not x.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to shuffle your list and then pick the first one that is not a number. Additionally, you could use a generator expression within `next` function by checking the type of items using `str.isalpha()`.  For example:

```
In [11]: import random 
    ...: s = 'hi there 3'
    ...: lst = s.split()
    ...: random.shuffle(lst)
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [12]: next(i for i in lst if i.isalpha())
Out[12]: 'there'
```